# What does a 'free variable' mean? // Quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I've researched about the Quantifiers but couldn't find any material that explains 'free variables'.

Question:

```
>  Determine the truth set of:

>                             ∀y (x . y < x) 

>   where x,y are from the universe of real numbers.
```

Answer:

[Answer picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5duV3.png)

my question is what is the meaning of 'free' and how this answer came up to empty.

Comment: Where/how is $x$ quantified?

Comment: For [free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).

Comment: For [truth-set](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truth%20set).

Comment: A formula with a free var is a formula with an "empty place" (and a free variable is a "trick" to write expressions with a "place-holder"). For every *value* assigned to the free var (i.e. for every value that fills the empty place) the formula becomes a *sentence*, i.e. an expression that has a definite truth value.

Comment: For "how this answer came up to empty", consider the cases of $x = 0$ and $x \ne 0$ separately, and for $x \ne 0$ , divide both side of the equation by $x$.

Comment: Having said that, the formula $ ∀y (x \cdot y < x)$ means "for every real number $r$, the product $x \cdot r$" is less than $x$. Cosider as $r$ the number $1$: clearly $x \cdot 1 < x$ is false.

Comment: So the question is : what are the (real) number $x$ that satisfy the equation : $x \cdot r < x$, for every $r$ ? The set "collecting" all the values of $x$ (if any) is the *truth-set* of the formula.

Answer (score 4):

Free variables are variables that are not bound by a quantifier. The opposite of a free variable is a bound variable. Consider the statement "a divides b" in first order logic: $\exists x(a = b \times x)$. The variable $x$ is bound while $a$ and $b$ are free. In a sense the bound variable is really just a dummy variable, they are not key to the mathematical statement. The Mathematical statement $a$ divides $b$ is a statement about $a$ and $b$ as opposed to $x$. Informally you can think of bound variables as tools to help us describe the free or "meaningful" variables. We may change our $x$ to some variable, for example $\exists y(a = b \times y)$ is identical to the previous statement. But if we were to change our free variables the meaning of the statement would be fundamentally different. I would like to answer your second question but I cannot understand what was written on the second line as I do not know if $x$ and $y$ represent real numbers or some other mathematical objects.

Comment: The question states that x and y are from the universe of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I intend to give a heuristic instead of a pedantic illustration, so some terminologies may not be that standard in some logicians eyes.

Sometimes a proper example may explain more than a description. Consider the expression 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}5^{i}.
$$
Here the role of "$i$" is vacuous in the sense that you can replace "$i$" with whatever symbol you want without affecting the value of the sum. However, the role of "$n$" is different from that of "$i$"; for different values of $n$ affect the value of the sum. Here "$n$" is a free variable and "$i$" is a bound variable.

Regarding a logic context, consider the statement "There is some $x > 0$ such that $x=2y$". Here you may have noticed that the role of "$x$" is like that of "$i$" in the sense that you can replace "$i$" with whatever symbol you want without affecting 
the truth value of the statement (assuming $y$ given). However, in that statement the symbol "$y$" is not specified, so the statement could be true if $y = 1$, say, and false if $y < 0$. Since different values of $y$ affect the truth value of the statement, it is a free variable.